# Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '*'

Tags: javascript, java, formatting, format

This is how I call the method.

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        customPrint(7,10);
```

This is my method

```
public static void customPrint(int intValue, int fieldWidth) {
        System.out.printf("%*%d", fieldWidth, intValue); 
    }
```

My motive is to use the fieldwith as a variable in the printf statement and output the integer with the field with.
However I get an error:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '*'
Any solutions?

Expected output
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waBLB.png)

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: The expected output is

Comment: I think you might need to rethink on the logic since I don't see how you can get the expected output with the given logic. Also my answer would only fix the error then.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question we cannot specify the correct output for your program. But the error is occurred due to the first argument given to the `printf()` method.

- If you want the two integers to appear then it is `System.out.printf("%d%d", fieldWidth, intValue);`.
- Else if it is string with integer it is `System.out.printf("%s%d", "fieldWidth", intValue);`.